# In QGIS map composer, how do I get the Item Properties dialog back?

Tags: qgis, printing

Yes, well if there is button there, one is bound to click it....
I closed both the Item Properties dialogs in Map Composer.

And I can't get them to give me any joy no more...

QGIS Trunk

Comment: for me this did not work ; when I right click in the toolbar an empty Item Properties panel pops up as a new window. When I did the same for Atlas it actually did work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right click on a empty spot in the toolbar and select **Item Properties**

Comment: the other dialog is actually called Composition.. All good.